# Implementation of recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, path-finding, brute-force

I've got two kinds of object, `Ball` and `Platform`. Balls have an `(x,y)` coordinate and the platforms have `(x_begin, x_end, y)`. There can be at most 80 Platforms.

I was asked to find the shortest path for any given `Ball` to the ground (`y=0`). Note that the output of this should only be the minimum distance.

Given the constraints I thought it would be best to use brute force: calculate all the possible distances to the ground, and then return the minimum.

[image: Fig.1]

What I thought I'd do, is write a recursive function: first calculate the vertical distance to the nearest platform, and then branch into right and left, and back again. The breaking condition would be when all paths reach the ground.

```
    void calculateDistances(Ball b, vector<Platform> ps, vector<float>* distances)
    {
        //The idea is to have, for every branch
        // distances[i] = vertical distance
        // distances[i+1] = distance to right
        // distances[i+2] = distance to left
        Platform* p = NULL;
        float d_y = verticalDistanceToNearestPlatform(ps, p); // "p" now holds the platform the ball is on
        if (d_y == 0) 
            return; //already on floor
        distances->push_back(d_y);

        d_x_right = distanceToRightEdgeOfPlatform(p);
        distances->push_back(d_x_right);
        d_x_left = distanceToLeftEdgeOfPlatform(p);
        distances->push_back(d_x_left);
    }
```

The problem here is obvious... how on Earth do I make this recursive?

Many thanks!

PS: this problem is meant to be solved in approximately two and a half hours.

Comment: @honk, no; this problem was part of an exam that lasted 2.5 hours.

Comment: Well, the keywords "recursive breadth depth first" come to mind which bring up some duplicates on this site.

Comment: Yes I thought of that as well, but have no idea how to adapt it to my code lol

Comment: This is actually a path finding problem. Try using the A* algorithm with height as the heuristic.

Comment: Nice visual, really helps.

Comment: Also keep in mind the vertical distance will be the same for all paths, so can be ignored entirely.

Comment: @MooingDuck, you're right! But I don't see how I can make the algorithm simpler with that information :S

Comment: I've updated my answer as per @MooingDuck's suggestion - maybe that helps you to understand? Basically, instead of finding the distance (total), you need only find the horizontal distance to the nearest point on the ground, then add the vertical distance later. You can really just cut all code relating to the vertical component from the recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive solution (say, `horizontalDistanceToGround(x, y)`) would involve computing the horizontal distance from some arbitrary point `(x, y)` to the nearest point on the ground, as follows:

- If there's no platform between `(x, y)` and the ground, then return 0.
- If there's any platform between `(x, y)` and the ground, then find the nearest such platform (i.e. that has the greatest `platform_y` less than `y`). If that platform is located at `(platform_min_x, platform_max_x, platform_y)`, then return the minimum of `(x - platform_min_x) + horizontalDistanceToGround(platform_min_x, platform_y)` and `(platform_max_x - x) + horizontalDistanceToGround(platform_max_x, platform_y)`. This basically computes the minimum distance needed to get from the current x position to an end of the platform, and from there to the ground.

I'll leave finding the nearest platform between `(x, y)` and the ground (if there is one) to you to figure out.

The shortest distance from ball to ground is then `distanceToGround(ball_x, ball_y) + ball_y`.

**NOTE:** Updated as per @MooingDuck's useful comment regarding the vertical distance being irrelevant to the recursion.

Comment: +1, but by rearranging the function to take parameters `whichPlatform` and `goLeft` instead of `x` and `y`, and return the smallest distance to ground from the `(goLeft ? left : right)` edge of the given platform, it's possible to memoise the function efficiently (i.e. apply dynamic programming), so that the runtime comes down from exponential to quadratic.

Comment: You can avoid the memory hit of memoization by simply tracking all possible ball positions at a particular altitude. This is nonrecursive and O(n^2) worst case (stairstep platform pattern) but closer to linear in practice if the platforms tend to be over each other.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert this problem into a graph problem and then use any number of graph-searching algorithms to solve it.

To do so, loop through all the platforms and create nodes for each of their edges and for any points directly beneath the edge of another platform. Connect all the nodes that share a common platform together. Make the vertical connections as well.

Perform the same operation for the ground, but don't add additional nodes for the edges and don't connect the ground nodes

Now, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm (a reconstructive variant) to search your graph for the shortest path between the top and *each* point on the bottom. Choose the result with the lowest value and you're done. Dijkstra's algorithm runs in O(N^2), where N is a node, for a naive implementation and O(E+N log N) where E is an edge for a smart implementation.

You could also use A*, which may be easier to implement in a pinch.

Searching to see what platform a ball falling off the edge will hit is easy. Treat the ground as a platform. Sort the platforms by height. For each platform walk linearly through all the platforms beneath it, starting with the closest one. See if the x value of the higher platform falls in the range defined by the edges of the lower platform. This takes O(P^2). (P is number of platforms.)

This may not answer your question directly (i.e. this is not brute force), but I think it's a better direction to point you in. Plus, if you try to brute force all the directions the ball can go it ends up being something like O(2^P), which is an unpleasantly high time complexity.